# Stop service started at boot

Tags: android, service, boot, fileobserver

I'm creating an android app that runs a service via a broadcast receiver at startup. The service, in turn, runs a fileobserver class to monitor a directory. When creating a file in the monitored directory, i need the service to restart. Is it possibile to restart the service in the fileobserver class event?

Comment: Instead of restarting the service, couldn't you use the FileObserver to reset the state of your already running service when a file/directory change is detected?

Comment: Bradford2000 thanks for the reply. Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this and not have to restart your Service (just update the Service state as file change events are detected).

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private FileObserver observer;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, final int flags, final int startId) {
        init("path/to/watch");
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(final Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void init(final String pathToWatch) {
        observer = new FileObserver(pathToWatch) {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(final int event, @Nullable final String path) {
                onFileChangeEvent(path);
            }
        };
        observer.startWatching();
    }

    private void onFileChangeEvent(final String path) {
        if(condition) {
            observer.stopWatching();
            init("new/path/to/watch");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good. In my app, however, I need to dynamically change the path monitored by the fileobserver quite often or to terminate the old fileobserver instance and start another with the new path. For this reason I thought, at first, to finish the service and re-run it with the new path. What do you suggest?

Comment: For that, you can stop the current FileObserver and start a new one. I'll update my answer to illustrate.

Comment: Many thanks Bradford2000 for your valuable contribution. I solved my problem based on your answer.